Remove the hanging indentations from the glossary descriptions
I'd like to remove the hanging indentations from the glossary description texts (make them lean to the left / make the left indentation zero / make it left adjusted? I don't know the exact right term here) (update: proper terming is suggested: "remove the hanging indentation" I've edited the title accordingly)
Here's my "almost-Minimum" Working Example (using the command line sequence: lualatex main.tex, makeglossaries main, lualatex main.tex)
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
 
\newglossaryentry{fondue}
{
  name=Fondue,
  description={is a Swiss dish consisting of melted cheese that is served in a communal pot heated over a portable stove using a candle or a spirit lamp. It is eaten with bread using long-stemmed forks.}
}
 
\newglossaryentry{raclette}
{
  name=Raclette,
  description={is a Swiss dish that is also popular in France. It involves heating cheese and scraping off the melted portion and topping it onto meats or vegetables.}
}

\newacronym{msg}{MSG}{Monosodium glutamate}
\newacronym{oz}{OZ}{Ounce}

\title{Different Types of Cheese Dishes in Europe}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% LINE ABOVE TAKEN FROM: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197222/formatting-for-glossaries
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{1.0\linewidth}
% LINE ABOVE TAKEN FROM: latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14317, IN AN ATTEMPT
% (IN VEIN) TO MAKE THE description'S LEFT INDENT ZERO / LEAN FULLY TO THE LEFT

\glssetwidest{} % NOT USEFUL AT ALL

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Gls{fondue} is a very popular dish and is often associated with \gls{raclette}.
 
\clearpage
 
\printglossary[nonumberlist] % type=main,style=long]
% THE LINE ABOVE: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13162/how-to-prevent-page-numbers-from-appearing-on-glossaries
\end{document}



"lean to the left" sounds like reverse italics.  I think you might want to "remove the hanging indentation".  That's about all that I can contribute here.

Your MWE is not minimal, and when I compile it I don't get anything like your output.

The glossary, due to nonumberlist, uses description and you can exploit enumitem to set the margin.
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeglossaries
 
\newglossaryentry{fondue}
{
  name=Fondue,
  description={is a Swiss dish consisting of melted cheese that is served
    in a communal pot heated over a portable stove using a candle or a
    spirit lamp. It is eaten with bread using long-stemmed forks.}
}
 
\newglossaryentry{raclette}
{
  name=Raclette,
  description={is a Swiss dish that is also popular in France. It involves
    heating cheese and scraping off the melted portion and topping it onto
    meats or vegetables.}
}

\newacronym{msg}{MSG}{Monosodium glutamate}
\newacronym{oz}{OZ}{Ounce}

\title{Different Types of Cheese Dishes in Europe}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{1.0\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\Gls{fondue} is a very popular dish and is often associated with \gls{raclette}.

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=0pt} 
\printglossary[nonumberlist] % type=main,style=long]

\end{document}


